# @font-face with data URI in IE8 does not work

Tags: fonts, base64, data-uri

I cannot get my custom font in Internet Explorer 8 encoded with base64 in data URI. Here are my fon-face css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('data:application/x-font-woff;base64,[BASE_64_HERE]'), 
         url('data:font/eot;base64,[BASE_64_HERE]') format('embedded-opentype');
}
```

It works great in Chrome but does not work in IE8.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure ie8 doesn't support multiple src declarations. Having said that, I'm doing the same thing:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('data:font/eot;base64,[BASE_64_HERE]') format('embedded-opentype');
 }
```

and it still doesn't work in ie8. I'm thinking maybe a syntax issue? I hope someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

"[data-uris] was failing in IE 7/8 when I tried to apply it to a body font using multiple font files for different weights and styles. The solution I found is to simply set the font-weight and font-style in both @font-face declarations. Simple."

source: https://medium.com/what-i-learned-building/2c1de247c94e

Answer (score 0):

The traditional `@font-face` declaration for IE8 is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot');
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

If you want to use embedded URIs you have to split the `@font-face` into two declarations:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url(data:...)  format('woff'), 
         url(data:...)  format('truetype'),
         url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

Make sure all font styles (`font-style` or `font-weight`) are duplicated on both `@font-face` declarations.

See http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations for using Data URIs with ie8. According to caniuse.com:

"Support is limited to images and linked resources like CSS files, not HTML or JS files. Max URI length is 32KB."